# Pass hash reference in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

I am trying to pass a hash reference in Perl 5.8.8, which I know should be a pretty trivial thing. I pass hashes all over the place in my code, but for some reason it does not work in this subroutine:

```
sub build_results_hash {
    my %results;
    my $search = $_[0];
    my $json = $_[1];
    my $json_passed = $_[2];

    my $dbh = db_connect(-db=>'ghgs');

    my $db_search = html_db_input($search,$dbh);
    %results = db_hoh(-query=>"SELECT listing_id,MATCH(search) AGAINST($db_search) as relevance FROM search WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST($db_search) LIMIT 1000",-key=>"listing_id",-dbh=>$dbh);

    if(($json_passed == 1) and ($json ne '[]'))
    {
        narrow_results_hash(\%results,$search,$dbh,$json);
    }

    db_x($dbh);

    return \%results;
}

sub db_hoh {
    # ...
    return %hoh;
}
```

`db_hoh` just returns a hash of hashes. The issue is when I call `narrow_results_hash` and pass `%results`; it does not work. However, if I remove the `if` statement that surrounds that method call, then the hash is passed fine! I am not sure what would cause that behavior. Here is how I receive the hash:

```
sub narrow_results_hash
{
    use JSON::XS;
    my $params = shift;
    my %results = %$params;
    # ...
    print join(',',keys %results), "\n";
    # ...
}
```

If I remove the `if` statement around the `narrow_results_hash` call in `build_results_hash`, it prints: "107,99,34". However, if the `if` statement is present around the call, it prints "HASH(0x7fd61fbf0580)".

Comment: What, exactly, [do you mean](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) by "does not work"? Also, please reduce the sample code to a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/). As it is, it's not standalone.

Comment: Re "I pass hashes all over the place in my code", one cannot pass hashes to subs (just a list of scalars), and subs cannot return hashes (just a list of scalars).

Comment: Use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to look at `%results` and make sure it's a hash of hashes as you believe. I tried looking up the db_hoh method, but couldn't find it in the DBI documentation. I suspect that `db_hoh` is probably returning a ***reference*** to a hash of hashes.

Answer (score 2):

I have too many comments for a comment.

To your actual question, we need to know a few things to be able to help you.

1. What does `db_hoh` return, a reference to a hash, or a list of key-value pairs.
2. How do you mean, "Does not work"? Is it failing to work at all? Does it complete some operation, but give you an unexpected result?

Further, I have some stylistic comments on your code. It looks to me that you come from a C world, am I right?

1. Unpacking `@_` as a list assignment is cleaner looking
2. Declaring `%results` can wait until it is populated
3. Unless I misunderstand, you don't need to use `$json_passed` but rather you can test if `$json` is defined
4. In the `narrow` sub, you can avoid creating `$params`

Here is the updated code:

```
sub build_results_hash {
    my ($search, $json) = @_; 

    my $dbh = db_connect(-db=>'ghgs');

    my $db_search = html_db_input($search,$dbh);
    my %results = db_hoh(
      -query=>"SELECT listing_id,MATCH(search) AGAINST($db_search) as relevance FROM search WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST($db_search) LIMIT 1000",
      -key=>"listing_id",
      -dbh=>$dbh
    );

    if((defined $json) and ($json ne '[]'))
    {
        narrow_results_hash(\%results,$search,$dbh,$json);
    }

    db_x($dbh);

    return \%results;
}

sub narrow_results_hash
{
    use JSON::XS; #unless you expect this import to be local it looks funny here
    my %results = %{ shift() };
    # ...
}
```

Finally, and possibly most importantly, unless `html_db_input` is cleaning the input which is stored in `$db_search`, you are leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. It looks as though you have your own DB accessing library, but if you were using [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) I would do something like:

```
my $dbh = ...; # connect to db
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT listing_id,MATCH(search) AGAINST(?) as relevance FROM search WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST(?) LIMIT 1000');
$sth->execute($db_search,$db_search);
my $results = $sth->fetchall_hashref('listing_id');
```

This prevents the contents of `$db_search` from changing your SQL statement.

Comment: To answer your initial questions, 1. The return line at the end of the db_hoh() method is "return %hoh;"
2. In my narrow_results_hash method, I use join on my %results hash like this "join(',',keys %results);" If I print this and I remove the if statement around the narrow_results_hash call, I get a list like this: "107,99,34". However, if the if statement is present around the call, I get this: HASH(0x7fd61fbf0580).

Comment: what version of Perl are you using? From version [5.14](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta) many functions (like [`keys`](http://p3rl.org/keys)) can take references as well as hashes (or arrays) and they will be dereferenced automatically. Since your result from a direct print is HASH(0xnnnnnnn) you definitely have a hashref and not a hash. It looks as though it needs further dereferencing.

Comment: Ok well I think we need to see the whole `narrow_hash_results` function

Comment: @srchulo: please update the question with your clarifications. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 1):

db_hoh probably returns a hash reference rather than a hash. Try using a scalar as your results variable.

```
my %results;
```

becomes

```
my $results;
```

and so on...